# Grails External configuration Config System.getenv

Tags: grails, config, getenv

i have code in config.groovy

```
def ENV_NAME = "/home/myFolder"

if(System.getenv("ENV_NAME")) {
    println( "Including configuration file: " + System.getenv("ENV_NAME"));
    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.getenv("ENV_NAME")
} else {
    println "No external configuration file defined."
}
```

When I run, the result is "*No external configuration file defined.*"
What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably that there isn't an environment variable named `ENV_NAME` defined at the point when you ran the app.

Comment: hi ian, i got example from http://www.baselogic.com/blog/development/java-javaee-j2ee/getting-grails-external-configuration-working-in-the-real-world/ so i wonder to know how to define environment variable in config

Comment: It depends on the platform and the app server in question. Using Tomcat on Ubuntu I would set environment variables by editing `bin/catalina.sh` or the `/etc/init.d` script, I don't know how to do it on Windows.